# CKEditor integrated prints wrong image path

Tags: forms, ckeditor4.x

I integrated CKEditor to a webpage.

I have already previously uploaded images I'd like to insert.

Initially it works fine, images display correctly.  However, when posted to the other page, using post form method, they print the wrong path and don't show up.

Using the inspector, i see that there's a `\"` inserted at beggining and end of the image source.

So it shows: `<img src:"\"domain.com/template/images/someimage.jpg\"">`

When should be: `<img src:"domain.com/template/images/someimage.jpg">`

How can I prevent this? Is it a server issue?

Comment: Seems like this is a matter of escape characters being printed.

Answer (score 0):

i did some more research and found an answer that solved the problem.

in the output page there was: 
`echo $_POST["mytextarea"];`

i had to define a variable with stripslashes.

so:

```
 $content = stripslashes ( $_POST['mytextarea']); 
    echo $content;
```

well done!